# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in chronoline.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

js. I am Populating Datas Using Loop,parse to json and given to valid input of this Plugin But i am Getting Error in that. I am Just Adding Events From The Function sbuilder()--> After Population I am just Giving datas to that particular plugin variable events

My Code :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        thirdtimeliner();
    });     

    function sbuilder() {
        var str = "";
        var i = 0;
        var today = new Date();
        var date = today.getDate();
        for (i; i <= date; i++) {
            str = str.concat("{dates:[new Date(2014,1," + i + ")] , title:'5GB', section:0 , attrs:{fill:'#468847',stroke:'#468847'}},");
        }
        var json = str.substring(0, str.length - 1);
        var events = "[" + json + "]";
        return events;
    }


   function thirdtimeliner() {
        var strin = sbuilder();
                alert(strin);
                var eventsr = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + strin + ")"));        
                alert(eventsr);

                var events = eventsr;
        var sections = [
                { dates: [new Date(2014, 1, 1), new Date(2014, 1, 12)],
                    title: "2014 Status",
                    section: 0,
                    attrs: { fill: "#dff0d8" },
                    draggable: true
                },
                { dates: [new Date(2014, 1, 10), new Date(2014, 1, 11)],
                    title: "2GB",
                    section: 0,
                    attrs: { fill: "#dff0d8" },
                    draggable: true
                },
                { dates: [new Date(2014, 1, 11), new Date(2014, 1, 12)],
                    title: "2GB",
                    section: 0,
                    attrs: { fill: "#dff0d8" },
                    draggable: true
                },
                { dates: [new Date(2014, 1, 12), new Date(2014, 1, 13)],
                    title: "processing..",
                    section: 0,
                    attrs: { fill: "#FFDE00" },
                    draggable: true
                },
                { dates: [new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 1, 8)],
                    title: "2014 Status",
                    section: 0,
                    attrs: { fill: "#ccc" },
                    draggable: true
                }
            ];


        var timeline1 = new Chronoline(document.getElementById("target1"), events,
    { animated: true,
        tooltips: true,
        defaultStartDate: new Date(),
        sections: sections,
        sectionLabelAttrs: { 'fill': '#997e3d', 'font-weight': 'bold' }
    });

    }
```

[image]

Expected Output :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with the events variable. You are sending events as a string(but chronoline needs an array object).

```
 var timeline1 = new Chronoline(document.getElementById("target1"), events,
{ animated: true,
    tooltips: true,
    defaultStartDate: new Date(),
    sections: sections,
    sectionLabelAttrs: { 'fill': '#997e3d', 'font-weight': 'bold' }
});
```

However in chronoline.js, events is treated as an array

```
for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < events[i].dates.length; j++){
        events[i].dates[j] = new Date(events[i].dates[j].getTime());
        events[i].dates[j].stripTime();
    }
}
```

and the events string you are sending will look like

```
"[{"dates":["2014-01-30T18:30:00.000Z"],"title":"5GB","section":0,"attrs": {"fill":"#468847","stroke":"#468847"}},...]"
```

So events[0] is '[', events[1] is '{', events[2] is '"', events[3] is 'd' and so on...

In your case, events[i].date is undefined, so you are getting the error

```
Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Please check your code and send a proper Array of objects

Comment: hi will You Give the Solution For This Problem

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    thirdtimeliner();
});     

function sbuilder() {
    var array = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    var date = new Date().getDate();
    for (i; i <= date; i++) {
        array.push({dates:[new Date(2014,1,i)] , title:'5GB', section:0 , attrs:{fill:'#468847',stroke:'#468847'}});
    }
    return array;
}

function thirdtimeliner() {
    var events = sbuilder();

    var sections = [
            { dates: [new Date(2014, 1, 1), new Date(2014, 1, 12)],
                title: "2014 Status",
                section: 0,
                attrs: { fill: "#dff0d8" },
                draggable: true
            },
            { dates: [new Date(2014, 1, 10), new Date(2014, 1, 11)],
                title: "2GB",
                section: 0,
                attrs: { fill: "#dff0d8" },
                draggable: true
            },
            { dates: [new Date(2014, 1, 11), new Date(2014, 1, 12)],
                title: "2GB",
                section: 0,
                attrs: { fill: "#dff0d8" },
                draggable: true
            },
            { dates: [new Date(2014, 1, 12), new Date(2014, 1, 13)],
                title: "processing..",
                section: 0,
                attrs: { fill: "#FFDE00" },
                draggable: true
            },
            { dates: [new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 1, 8)],
                title: "2014 Status",
                section: 0,
                attrs: { fill: "#ccc" },
                draggable: true
            }
        ];


    var timeline1 = new Chronoline(document.getElementById("target1"), events,
{ animated: true,
    tooltips: true,
    defaultStartDate: new Date(),
    sections: sections,
    sectionLabelAttrs: { 'fill': '#997e3d', 'font-weight': 'bold' }
});

}
```

Hope this will work. :)

Comment: Same error! How can it be possible. We are sending Array of objects. Can you please send the screenshot of the error?